Why anti-de Sitter space is time-orientable?
Consider the real vector space $\mathbb R^{2,2} = (\mathbb R^{4}, b)$ with the non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form of signature $(2,2)$ $$b(x,y) = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2-x_3y_3-x_4y_4$$
We define the quadric model of anti-de Sitter space as $$\text{AdS}^3 = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid b(x,x) =-1\}$$ Let $x \in \text{AdS}^3$, then $T_x \text{AdS}^3 = x^{\perp}$ Now $\text{AdS}^3$ with $b\Big|_{x^{\perp}}$ is a Lorentzian manifold of dimension $3$. I want to prove that $\text{AdS}^3$ is time-orientable.
In each tangent space of a Lorentzian manifold $M$ the set of timelike vectors consists of two connected components. We choose a time-orientation  by picking one of these two connected components, denoted by $I_+$ and call its elements future-directed, otherwise past directed. A time-orientation is given by a continuous timelike vector field $\tau$ on $M: \tau (p) \in I_+ \subset T_pM$ for all $p\in M$.
Now I have proved that $\text{AdS}^3$ is homomorphic to $\mathbb H^n \times S^1$ where $\mathbb H^2$ is as one connected component of the two-sheeted hyperboloid in Minkowksy space, under the map $f: \mathbb H^2 \times S^1 \rightarrow \text{AdS}^3$, defined by $$f((x_1, x_2, x_3), \theta) = (x_1, x_2, x_3 cos \theta, x_3 sin \theta).$$
Now I cannot proceed further.
